# while updating same table in mysql skipping some row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update same table by join of same table, duplicate row skipping.I want to store duplicate value's count in number_of_duplicates field.

```
UPDATE 4_crem_three_entries a,(
    SELECT count(*) c,cream_id FROM 4_crem_three_entries 
    GROUP BY `c_phone` HAVING count( * ) >1
   ) b
SET number_of_duplicates=b.c 
WHERE a.cream_id=b.cream_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE 4_crem_three_entries 
SET number_of_duplicates=(SELECT count( * ) FROM 4_crem_three_entries c where c.cream_id=4_crem_three_entries.cream_id GROUP BY c.c_phone HAVING count( * ) >1)
```